# On keyup event not firing when binding a model in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-stickit

I am using require.js and stickit for model binding. 'change' event works fine, but if i use keyup for focusout the checkBindings() function does not fire. Why is this so?

```
        Stickit = require('stickit'),
        ApplicantModel = require('application/models/applicantModel'),
        template = _.template(tpl),
        applicantView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.checkBinding); //Change works fine, but keyup, focusout and other events do not fire
        this.render();
    },
    checkBinding: function() {
                console.log('Inside check binding functions');
                var data = this.model.toJSON();
                console.log($('#applicantInfoFirstName').val());
                console.log($('#applicantInfoMiddleName').html(JSON.stringify(data.middleName)));
    },    
    bindings: {
        '#applicantInfoFirstName': 'firstName',
        '#applicantInfoMiddleName': 'middleName',
        '#applicantInfoLastName':'lastName'
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("Inside applicant view");
        //Render application header
        this.$el.html(template);
        this.stickit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The events are specific to changes in the model. The list of events are [here](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Events)